# Cannot manipulate files in home directory using native Windows programs

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed the Linux subsystem for Windows and one of the first things I tried was to edit my `.bashrc` which is located at `/home/user` in file system of the Linux subsystem, or `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\lxss\home` in plain Windows. I did so using a Windows program.

After I saved the file, whenever I start bash I get an input/output error related to `/home/user/.bashrc` and `ls` no longer lists `.bashrc` as it used to.

Furthermore, I noticed that when I create new files using Windows programs in `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\lxss\home`, they don't show in the output of `ls ~`. Conversely, it works as expected: whatever I do in `/home/user` using bash, it's properly shown in `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\lxss\home`.

I was under the impression that `/home/user` and `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\lxss\home` were the same directory which could be manipulated in either the Linux subsystem or Windows. Is it not so?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the exact error you see? 

Can you see the files listed if you run `ls -al`?

It maybe that editing the files via Windows is messing up the file permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not the case.

It is [the expected behavior with Windows on Linux](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1152#issuecomment-250938896).

Linux file system requires additional metadata that Windows does not understand, you are not supposed to access the files in the `lxss` directory via Windows.

[This Microsoft blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/06/15/wsl-file-system-support/) goes into a bit more detail.

Comment: There are many workarounds and solutions in the corresponding [issue report in Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1524).

Comment: @Jaime Yes, in the last two years there have been a lot of changes to WSL and what can be done.